# Shortened citation title is missing from biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-chicago, multiple-citations

I'm working with the latest version of biblatex-chicago and use autocite to cite sources. When I reference a source multiple times, the shortened form of the citation is used, but this seems to only include the author and page number, not the (shortened) title.  How can I make sure that the title is also included?

My main.tex file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[notes, useprefix=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{references}

\begin{document} 

This is an example of a first citation. \autocite[p. 166]{baudrillard2020simulacra} Now here is a repeated citation that misses the title. \autocite[p. 3]{baudrillard2020simulacra} 

\end{document}
```

And my references.bib is as follows:

```
@book{baudrillard2020simulacra,
   title =     {Simulacra and Simulation},
   shorttitle = {Simulacra},
   author =    {Jean Baudrillard},
   publisher = {University of Michigan Press},
   location = {Ann Arbor, Michigan},
   year =      {1994},
}
```

This looks like this, the shortened title/title is missing:
[image: renderedfootnotes]

Comment: Please share an example document (including a relevant `.bib`) entry that we can compile and that shows the issue. I could not reproduce the problem in https://gist.github.com/moewew/147e9b8ea652f6a4ba1bcd28ebd60ce0, where the `angenendt` entry has a `shorttitle`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edited my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a difference in how `biblatex-chicago` handles subsequent citations of a work. Normally the short form in subsequent citations uses author and title, but if the work cited is the same as the previously cited work (e.g. the "ibid." tracker yields true), the title is also dropped. I'm not sure if this is correct behaviour according to CMoS, if it is not, please report this to the maintainer of `biblatex-chicago`. He is usually very eager to help and fix issues with his style.

Here is a quick workaround to always show author and title in short citations.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:short:ibid}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:short}{\thefield{entrytype}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{baudrillard2020simulacra,
  title      = {Simulacra and Simulation},
  shorttitle = {Simulacra},
  author     = {Jean Baudrillard},
  publisher  = {University of Michigan Press},
  location   = {Ann Arbor, Michigan},
  year       = {1994},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document} 
This is an example of a first citation. \autocite[2]{baudrillard2020simulacra}
Now here is a repeated citation that misses the title.\autocite[3]{baudrillard2020simulacra} 

This is an example of a first citation. \autocite[166]{nussbaum}
Now here is a repeated citation that misses the title.\autocite[4]{baudrillard2020simulacra} 
This is an example of a first citation. \autocite[167]{nussbaum}
This is an example of a first citation. \autocite[168]{nussbaum}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1. Jean Baudrillard, Simulacra and Simulation (Ann Arbor, Michigan: University of Michigan Press, 1994), 2.//2. Baudrillard, Simulacra, 3.]

Comment: I think dropping the short title when previously ibid would have been used is a feature of CMoS 17.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it works perfectly! @David, about the 17th edition, I checked the CMoS and I believe you're right. The title can still be included though, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @Paperclip If the answer worked for you and solved your problem, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the green checkmark at the top left of the answer) to mark the question as resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.